# Use loop to initialize multiple objects

Tags: c#, algorithm, decision-tree, id3

I am trying to build the ID3 algorithm on the [promoters data](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/molecular-biology/promoter-gene-sequences/promoters.data) which contain 58 attributes. How can I instead of insitializing each single attribute use a loop (such as for or foreach) to initalise all?

bascially instead of doing the below I want do it with a loop but I cannot use a loop inside the curlies

```
var splits = line.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        var name = splits[1];
        var data = splits[2].Trim();
        string[] array = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            array[i]= data.ToCharArray().GetValue(i).ToString();
        }

        return new Instance
        {
            Output = new Output(splits[0], "Result"),
            Features = new List<Feature>
                                  {
                                  new Feature(array[0], "1"),
                                  new Feature(array[1], "2"),
                                  new Feature(array[2], "3"),
                                  new Feature(array[3], "4"),
                                  //and so on for all atributes
                                  }
        };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
Features = Enumerable.Range(1, 58)
            .Select(x => new Feature(array[x - 1], x.ToString()))
            .ToList()
```

Comment: this seems good, however I am getting an error on the last line .ToList()

Comment: probably because you didn't include the namespace `using System.Linq;`

Comment: Feature does not contain a definition for 'ToList', then I tried adding the who select '.ToString()' and then '.ToList()' but then I get cannot convert type error

Comment: @rikket Are you sure you've put the `ToList` in the right place?

Comment: @benAaronson yes afaik, I did it exactly like Selman22 posted

Comment: I am not very familiar with linq though

Comment: sorry, I missed one parenthesis after Select.

Comment: my bad I forgot to add a bracket

Answer (score 0):

The other answer is good, and you should definitely become familiar with LINQ for situations like these. However if you want to see how this can be done easily with language features you're already familiar with, you could just do:

```
var features = new List<Feature>();
for(int i = 0; i < 58; i++)
{
    features.Add(new Feature(array[i], (i+1).ToString()));
}
```

Then you'd assign this when creating the `Instance`:

```
return new Instance
{
    Output = new Output(splits[0], "Result"),
    Features = features
};
```